# Ruby - Finding the data in specific field/key of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I collected a list of all tags of my github repo using github api. Suppose I store it in a variable named 'released_tags'.

Eg: `Data in 'released_tags' would be something similar to data displayed in https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/tags`

I have a number 0.3 and I wish to find it in the value of the name field of this data and want the last/latest containing/matching name.

Expected result: This data has 0.3.5, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1 and 0.3.0 which contains 0.3. I am trying to work on a logic/easy way in which a search is made through name field for 0.3 and I get the latest i.e. in this case the output of the logic should be 0.3.5 since thats the latest/highest number. If the name field just had 0.3 or 0.3.0, then the output should be 0.3 or 0.3.0

***EDIT: I was able to get to the solution, but is there any easy/short way to do it? Here is my solution:***

```
 tag_names = Array.new

  released_tags.each do |tag|
    if tag['name'].include? '0.3'
      tag_names << tag['name']
    end
  end

 p tag_names.first
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you always need the first result that matches, you could use `find`:

```
released_tags.find { |tag| tag['name'] =~ /^0\.3/ }
```

or, if you don't like regular expressions:

```
released_tags.find { |tag| tag['name'].start_with?("0.3") }
```

Comment: Also, if you just need the tag name itself you can do this: `released_tags.map {|tag| tag['name'] }.grep(/0\.3/).first`

Comment: ...though that's probably less efficient =/